# How to quickly navigate to a certain position using VIM

Tags: vim, vi

Below is a code snippet that I get from the internet as an example. Say we are at line 48 (the secong input near the bottom), however, we need to go back to the second **of** at line 8.Do we just hit `:82o`?

What if the line number is really large (e.g., 1425) and there are a few of the same word within the line.

In this case, it will take many key strokes, even I have to hit `w` after I get to the line. How can VIM compete with a mouse in a scenario of random access of a certain word in a large file, in which case you just need to move your pointer with the mouse to achieve this?

**Edit**: The code is a snippet that I got from the internet in order to demostrate my question. The possible scenario could be I am working on line 1148 and I'd like to go back to line 1108 just to change a word in a comment or I need to fix a bug by making a little bit change within the line 1108. Therefore, the place to go back is hardly predictable and pretty much random.

**Edit**: I would prefer to know a best practice to achieve this with a vanilla Vim. But you can feel free to provide a solution based on a plugin.

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE> Banner</TITLE>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE= "javascript">
// Puts the text to scroll into variable called sent - SECTION A
// uses length propert to assess its length and put into variable slen
// initalizes a,b,n, and subsent variables
var sent = "This is a demonstration of a banner moving from the left to right. It makes use of the substring property of Javascript to make an interesting display"
var slen = sent.length
var siz = 25
var a = -3, b = 0
var subsent = "x"

// Creates a function to capture substrings of sent - SECTION B
function makeSub(a,b) {
subsent = sent.substring(a,b) ;
return subsent;
}

//Creates a function that increments the indexes of the substring - SECTION C 
//each time and calls the makeSub() function to geneate strings
//a indicates start of substring and siz indicates size of string required
function newMake() {
a = a + 3;
b = a + siz
makeSub(a,b);
return subsent
}

//function uses loop to get changing substrings of target - SECTION D
//repeatedly calls newMake to get next substring
//uses setTimeout() command to arrange for substrings to display 
// at specified times
function doIt() {
for (var i = 1; i <= slen ; i++) {
setTimeout("document.z.textdisplay.value = newMake()", i*300);
setTimeout("window.status = newMake()", i*300);
}
}

</SCRIPT> 
</HEAD>

<BODY >
<HR> <CENTER>
<FORM NAME="z">
<INPUT NAME="textdisplay" TYPE="text" SIZE=25> <P>
<INPUT NAME="doit" Type="button" value = "Run Banner" onClick = "doIt()"> 
</FORM></CENTER>

<HR>

</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: There is possibly different strategy's to handle this. I think most of the time, you are faster by searching the word instead of using the mouse. Of course this is a bad idea with something like "of" but i don't think it is a realistic example, since you nearly never search a filler word in a line you already know. And if you do, you have been there before and could set a mark. I like to use easymotion with incsearch for these cases https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion. However i am no pro and would be glad if somebody coul provide the perfect vim only solution =)

Comment: Maybe the plugin vim-easymotion is what you are looking for: https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion

Comment: Thanks, Doktor, I've updated the question to show the purpose of this question.

Comment: @ap0 The plugin looks cool. It provides a Vimperator-like approcah to highlight the keyword. I gotta try it out. I'd also like how people achieve this in a vanilla Vim.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to navigate if you know which word you should end up at is to search for it.

I'd do a `/of` to search for of and I'm there.

I find this easier than moving my mouse pointer.

Now coming to the scenario of really large files, `relativenumbers` can help you.

```
set relativenumber
```

Now to go from `1148` to `1104`, you can just do a `40k` then use <kbd>f</kbd> to get to desired character.

You can prefix <kbd>f</kbd> with numbers to move to nth appearance of that character. You can search too.

Again I find this easier than using mouse.

If you have enough command over searching and moving with <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> prefixed with motion numbers, you'll be faster than using mouse.

Comment: I had some performance problems with relativenumber, could be a plugin issue, so i would like to hear if you had issues with relativenumbers ? I see the advantage of relativenumbers but i have hard times getting used to it. It is just so much screen flicker. Do you use it all the time ?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo: No I've never experienced performance problems or flickering with relative numbering. Have you tried using relative numbers without any plugins or configuration?

Comment: no, as i said i had hard times getting used to a "non-static" screen (that was what i meant with flicker). But wanted to know if its a common issue. Since it is not, i will debugg it and get used to it. it is just a too powerful feature to not use it.

Comment: Here's a screencast of how my relative numbering works.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEDj7HXGsJE  

Is this what you call "non-static" screen?

Comment: yeah i mean the update of the line numbers. I have deactivated absolutly everything what changes the screen without a keypress from me (I use neocomplete in manual mode f.e.), and yes it silly, and i think i will get used to it, but i steals my focus if something updates the screen automatically ;-)

Comment: Alright. Just wanted to know if we're on the same page there. It'd be hard for you to switch between files then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136872/discussion-between-doktor-oswaldo-and-sudo-bangbang).

Answer (score 1):

Editing is not something you do at random like in your example. Navigation usually happens from one point of interest to another **related** point of interest, whether both POIs are part of the same task or parts of related tasks.

Your first example is very unrealistic for two reasons:

1. because there would be no reason whatsoever to jump from that first POI to that second POI as they are **completely** unrelated,
2. because the whole file may not fit wholly in the editing window, which would make the mouse largely irrelevant.

The only potentially useful navigation from your initial state would be to jump to the definition of the event handler, which is only a `?do<CR>` away. Note that the function is already under our nose so there's no need to navigate to begin with if all we want is to know what `doIt()` does.

Your second example is too abstract to work with.

The local navigation tools at your disposal correspond to various zoom levels:

- `gegEbBwWeE` at the word level,
- `fFtT;,0^$g_g^g$` at the line level,
- `(){}` at the paragraph level,
- `ggnG` at the buffer level,
- `nHMnL` at the window level,
- and a bunch of other commands at various levels like `hjkl` or `gm`.

But the most powerful of the lot is search, `?/nN` (together with `set incsearch`), which lets you jump directly to wherever you want with minimal effort.

Answer (score 0):

## Keyword Search

For random access, keyword search using `\{keyword}` is normally your best option. Although I have a feeling that this question (with its use of the word *of*) was geared to sabotage this method, I will point out that you could still run this search by just continuing to type the next word after *of*. With this approach we are looking at 5-7 keystrokes at most I'd say. That's quite a lot better than using the mouse if you ask me.

## EasyMotion

Several others have mentioned the [EasyMotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) project. I am not too familiar with this project so I will not comment on it any further.

## Why to *really* avoid the mouse?

I do not believe that the added efficiency one acquires by using Vim is the result of avoiding the mouse at all costs; rather, it is the result of training yourself to **avoid leaving the home row at all costs.** It is not the mechanics of the mouse but the constant task-switching between keyboard to mouse that slows us down the most.

Comment: "The vim philosophy is about how to avoid leaving the home row at all costs." Nope, not at all.

Comment: Well admittedly I was overgeneralizing a bit; however, that is close to how I really would try to sum it up if forced to do so in a sentence of two. Care to take a whack at it?

Comment: @romaini I have edited my answer with hopes that it is now a bit more politically correct.

Comment: `:s/politically/technically`.